# Can anyone solve this integral? $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{x^4+1}-x^2dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I thought of this peculiar integral: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{x^4+1}-x^2dx$$ and I'm wondering whether or not it has a closed-form solution.
I can show that this integral converges using the comparison theorem, since $$\sqrt{x^4+1}-x^2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}+x^2} < \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
but with the $\sqrt{x^4+1}$ , we also know that the function itself has no elementary integral. Any ideas?

Comment: Can someone help me? I'm confused. If you let $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^4+1)^{1/2}+z^2}$ (with, say, the principal branch of $\sqrt{.}$), then the integral over an upper semicircle with radius $R$ goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$; but also, $f$ has no poles because if $(z^4+1)^{1/2} = -z^2$, then $z^4+1 = z^4$, impossible. So, we should end up with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 0$, which is obviously false. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @mathworker21, $\sqrt{z^4+1}$ has the usual square-root branch problems wherever $z^4=-1$, which occurs twice on the upper half plane (and twice more on the lower half plane), so it is not holomorphic on the upper half plane, and thus Cauchy's residue theorem doesn't apply. (I.e., what saultpatz said in fewer words!)

Comment: @mathworker It has branch points at the fourth roots of -1.

Comment: One would expect to be able to deform the contour to one around a branch cut between the two roots of $\sqrt{z^4+1}$ in the upper half-plane. Whether this is actually a helpful approach is another matter.

Comment: Thanks! I've taken too long of a break from complex analysis :(

Comment: Also, wolfram makes the answer seem complicated, so I don't know if a deformation of contour trick would help.

Comment: Mathematica evaluates it suspiciously quickly, which leads me to suspect that it's got something to do with an elliptic integral. Ramanujan's Master Theorem gives $\Gamma(1/4)^2/(3\sqrt{\pi})$, which looks very similar to $K(1/2) = \Gamma(1/4)^2/(4\sqrt{\pi}) $.

Comment: Using integration by parts I found a simpler equivalent integral $$\frac{2}{3} \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}} \, dx$$, assuming $\left[ \frac{x^3}{3}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}}-1 \right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$

Comment: @Chappers. The antiderivative involves an nasty elliptic integral of the first kind

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Start with @JamesArathoon's integral, obtained by IBP:
$$\frac{4}{3}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}$$
Then, after an appropriate substitution, apply this well known formula using the Gamma function:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}=\mathrm{B}(m,n)$$